# PHP ротация логов

Tags: php, логирование

Как правильно реализовать логирование средствами php?

Предположим файл запускается каждую минуту по крону. При этом каждый раз создается новый файл. Как сделать ротацию предположим в день длиной?

Comment: используйте logrotate. для приложения это будет выглядеть просто как набивание одного и того же файла логами, а остальное возьмет на себя он.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в чем, в определении, когда нужно создавать новый файл, или в том, чтобы добавить запись в конец файла, а не создавать/перезаписывать каждый раз новый? Или может в том, что файл в принципе должен быть один, но все записи туда должны попадать и не стираться?

**Алгоритм:**

*1) Определить какой день сейчас*
*2) Задать имя файла*
*3) Сделать в него запись. Если такого файла не существует - автоматически создастся новый*

Если нужно **1 лог файл = 1 день**:

```
// Формируем сообщение и имя файла
$message = "Тест сообщения\r\n";
$file_name = date("Y_m_d")."_log.log"

// Запись в файл
$file = fopen("logs/$file_name", 'a+');
fwrite($file, $message);
```

Если нужно, чтобы был **один файл**, а не создавался на каждый день новый, то присвоить переменным такие значения:

```
// Формируем сообщение и имя файла
$message = date("Y_m_d")."##Текст сообщения\r\n";    
$file_name = "log_file.log";

// Запись в файл
...
```

**Запись в файл средствами PHP:**

```
// Формируем сообщение и имя файла
...
// Запись в файл
error_log($message, 3,"logs/".$file_name);
```

**Протокол Syslog**

PHP также имеет функции реализующие отправку сообщений в системный журнал.

- [openlog();](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.openlog.php)  - открывает для программы соединение к системному журналу
- [syslog();](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.syslog.php)   - генерирует и отправляет сообщение в системный журнал
- [closelog();](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.closelog.php) - закрывает соединение с системным журналом

Comment: Плюсующие проблема в том что на каждый день создаётьс свой фаил

Comment: @Naumov Т.е. новый файл НЕ должен создаваться? Или наоборот 1 день = 1 файл?

Answer (score 0):

В двух словах это выглядит так 
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.error-log.php
`error_log($mymessage)` и всё остальное за вас сделает syslog

с крона можно отправлять вывод в тотже syslog примерно так

```
cron.php | syslog -t mycron -p warning
```

и сделать настройку файла `syslog.conf` для фильтрации сообщений и пересылку в определённый фаил лога.

П.C. про второй вариант надо почитать доки будет...

Comment: может все таки слово ротация в вопросе главнее?

Answer (score -1):

Как вариант записывать все логи в какую-либо СУБД (MySQL. На крайняк SQLite). А там уже методом выборки выводить нужную информацию через веб-интерфейс или PHP-скриптом.

Если нужно именно в файлы, то брать имя файла в формате даты (гггг-мм-дд.log) и дописывать в конец новые данные. Но все зависит от выбранного Вами логгера.